# fill nested json from postman in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'm newbie in rails , I have rails app that let user to create filter group with the following api

```
def create
    @filter_group = ::FilterGroup.new(filter_group_params.merge(user: current_user))
    return render json: {errors: filter_group.errors},  status: 400 unless @filter_group.save

    render json: { message: "Filter Group successfully created." }, status: :created
  end
```

and this is my params

```
 def filter_group_params
    params.permit(:name, :filters, :app_id)
  end
```

this is my model

```
class FilterGroup < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :filters, Hash
  validates_each :filters do
    validates :filter, presence: true
  end
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :app
end
```

i expect the result of my api should be somethings like this

```
{
    "filter_group": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "filters": {"Gail": "Jesse", "Brandon": "Lynn", "Loraine": "Agueda", "Marya": "Dennis"},
            "name": "name"
        }
    ]
}
```

but my problem is on index api that when i want to index my result the inner json that filled in create api not fill, and shwed somthing like this

```
{
    "filter_group": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "filters": {},
            "name": "name"
        }
    ]
}
```

could please tell me what is my wronge?

Comment: This code is quite difficult to read as the key logic is hidden way out on the end of en extremely long line. It would be better if you used `if @filter_group.save ... else ... end` instead of `return` and `unless`. I also don't get how you expect that result when you're rendering `json: { message: "Filter Group successfully created." }`

Comment: You also don't most likely don't want to use `serialize`. Its a hack for ancient databases which involves using a varchar column to store serialized ruby objects. If you're using a modern database that support JSON/JSONB types the driver will handle serialization.

Comment: @max I think my description make you wrong I have two diffrent api that at first I have to create a filter_group in create api and then expect to have first result in index api but I got second result in index api --- about reading that you tell i try to follow the hand writing of project --- and about 'serialize' I did not know about that I change my code thanks

Comment: Well if you want ppl to actually understand your question provide a full example of the code running and except of the logs showing the request. You can't expect us to do anything with just half the picture.